# Enable firewall connection for python server from localhost

Tags: server, python

I want to connect python server from my localhost to Ubuntu, but I get the following error:

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... failed: Connection refused.
```

Comment: Connection Refused means that, typically, nothing is listening.  There is no firewall block on "localhost" connections by default.  However, if you do not have a Python program/server *listening* on port 8000, you can't *connect* to port 8000.  Show the output of `sudo ss -tulpn | grep ':8000'`.  If you have no output then your Python 'server' is not listening on port 8000

Comment: sudo ufw allow from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 8000

Comment: I've tried sudo ss -tulpn | grep ':8000' and nothing showing up.. I also had tried the sudo ufw .. but still didn't work as mpboden state usually no firewall block on "localhost" connections by default